# android progress dialog bar doubts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am using the following code to show dynamic progress dialog :

```
public void loading()
{
     final int WelcomeScreenDisplay=1000;
     progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
     progressDialog.setCancelable(true);

     progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
   progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(10);
    progressDialog.show();



     Thread WelcomeThread=new Thread()
     {
        int wait=0;
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                super.run();
                while(wait<WelcomeScreenDisplay)
                {
                     sleep(100);
                          //  progressDialog.setProgress(0);
                     progressDialog.incrementProgressBy(10);    
                        wait+=100;

                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
     };
     WelcomeThread.start();
}
```

but there is some problem as:
1) when calling this function on button click,then loading bar is displayed after 10-15 seconds and 
2) When user enter username and password and click on login button, then progress bar is being displayed and using intent when activity jump from Login page to another,then while loading the dynamic contents of 2nd page,a blank screen is display in between both the pages for 1-2 mins

I wanted to know that what changes I will implement so that this blank screen should not come...and my application jumps from 1 page to another when the loading completes.

Comment: Manage your threads, its occuring because of unmanaged threads..you should watch when the thread is getting started..!!

Comment: what about AsyncTask (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)? it will be better for your scenario.

Comment: but I am using a single thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AsyncTask whenever you are performing such operations . Here is a sample

```
class eval extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void>
{

    ProgressDialog d;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        d=ProgressDialog.show(MainScreen.this,"Please Wait","Populating  content...",true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        //perform the required operation of fetching contents
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        d.dismiss();
        // now call the required Activity

    }
}
```

Now in your program to call this task you need to do this

```
new eval().execute();
```

Make sure you do not have any operation in the main UI thread after this statement

Comment: I didn't get last line of ur answers as "Make sure you do not have any operation in the main UI thread after this statement"

Comment: Suppose you print a message saying "data fetch complete" after the new eval().execute() statement instead of inside the method onPostExecute() , then this message will be printed even before a successful data fetch is complete ... all this because you are using threads . So make sure that all the actions that have to be performed strictly after the data fetch are given in the onPostExecute() method ONLY ....

Comment: so i have to do all my coding of fetching contents and calling anothor activity using Intent inside onPostExecute() method..and is there any sequence of these methods in which they run?

Answer (score 0):

According to me AsyncTask will be best way for perform such task because in this case UI will be free to perform other task, otherwise UI will be hang during the task and also there is no worry about the thread manage.
you can try:

http://android-solution-sample.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-asynctask-example.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: ur blog is very helpful for me

Comment: Its my pleasure I could help u.

Comment: available any time any problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch your data in the doInBackground() method . While this is happening ... a progress dialog will be shown . You call another activity in the onPostExecute() . Yes the sequence of execution is onPreExecute() , then doInBackground() and finally the OnPostExecute() . Please remember That the doInBackground() method executes in a non UI Thread . So you cannot use toasts or alertDialogues here .